# translating php array into asp.net arraylist

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

I'm trying translate some php code into `asp.net` code

php code:

```
        function setOption ($result) {
            foreach ($result as $value) {

                $parentid[$value['id']] = $value['parentid'];   
                $subid[$value['parentid']][] = $value['id'];    
                $name[$value['id']] = $value['name'];           
                $display[$value['id']] = $value['display'];         
            }           

            return array($parentid, $subid, $name, $display);

        }
```

asp.net code

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList parentid = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList subid = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList name = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList display = new ArrayList();

DataTable tbl = ds.Tables[0];
for (int i = 0; i < tbl.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow myRow = tbl.Rows[i];
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(myRow["id"]);
    int parent_id = Convert.ToInt32(myRow["parent_id"]);
    int oid = Convert.ToInt32(myRow["oid"]);
    int dis = Convert.ToInt32(myRow["display"]);
    string title = myRow["title"].ToString();

    parentid.Insert(id, parent_id);
    subid.Insert();
    name.Insert(id, title);
    display.Insert(id, dis);
}

al.Add(parentid);
al.Add(subid);
al.Add(name);
al.Add(display);

return al;
```

but at `$subid[$value['parentid']][] = $value['id'];` is two dimensional array code, how do asp.net present it in asp.net arraylist code?

Comment: It might be a good idea to use a Dictionary (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) instead of an ArrayList for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Check out the Dictionary class for converting the $value array to C# equivalent.

Comment: is there any other than Dictionary which can allow duplication of index?